# Como Actualizar en JSP y Mysql Usando sentencia sql IN

Tags: mysql, jsp, java-ee

tengo una duda referente a la actualización de registros con jsp y mysql, usando consultas con sentencia IN , el problema que presento es que si selecciono 1 solo registro, el sistema me actualiza correctamente, pero si selecciono varios registros, entonces la consulta no se ejecuta.

Aquí el metodo de la clase que almacena la consulta sql.

```
public class GuiasDao {
ResultSet res;
Statement st;
PreparedStatement pst;

public ResultSet moverCarga(Vuelo v,Folio f)
{
    try {
        Connection conn=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();

         String SQLUpdate="";

         SQLUpdate="UPDATE tvas t\n" +
                  "INNER JOIN rvas r\n" +
                  "ON(t.rvas_cod_seq_rvas = r.cod_seq_rvas)\n" +
                  "INNER JOIN awb a\n" +
                  "on(r.awb_cod_seq_awb=a.cod_seq_awb)\n" +
                  "SET t.vlos_seq_vlos ='"+v.getIdVuelo()+"'\n" +
                  "WHERE a.awb in('"+f.getNumeroFolioCompleto()+"');";   
         pst=(PreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement(SQLUpdate);
         pst.executeUpdate(SQLUpdate);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GuiasDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex.getStackTrace());
    }
    return res;

}
}
```

Aquí el Servlet que atiende la petición y que solicita el acceso a la clase GuiasDao para obtener la información de la base de datos.

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    Vuelo vuelo1=new Vuelo();
    Folio f=new Folio();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Connection con=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
    GuiasDao gdao = new GuiasDao();
    ArrayList<Guia> guia = new ArrayList<Guia>();
    Guia  g=new Guia();

    vuelo1.setIdVuelo(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txt_id_vuelo_disp")));
    f.setNumeroFolioCompleto((request.getParameter("txt_mostrar_guias").toString()));
    PreparedStatement ps=(PreparedStatement)gdao.moverCarga(vuelo1, f);


   try {

    if(request.getParameter("txt_mostrar_guias")==null ||request.getParameter("txt_id_vuelo_disp")==null)
    {

        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>"
                + "<link rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet Mover carga</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

        out.println("<form>");
        out.println("<div class='form-row'>");

        out.println("<p> Error Debe seleccionar las guias que desea mover</p>");
        out.println("<input type='button' value='volver' onclik='location.href='movimientosCarga2.jsp''> Error Debe seleccionar las guias que desea mover</p>");   
    }
    else
    {

        out.println("<p> Registro Actualizado con exito </p>");
        out.println("<p> se ha asignado el vuelo :'"+vuelo1.getIdVuelo()+"'</p>");
        out.println("<p> Las guias afectadas son las siguientes:"+f.getNumeroFolioCompleto()+"</p>");
        out.println("<input type='button' class='btn btn-primary' value='volver' ONCLICK=location.href='movimientosCarga2.jsp'>");
    }

        out.println("</div>");
        out.println("</form>"); 

    }
    catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException ex)
    {
        out.println("<h1>'"+ex.getMessage()+"'</h1>");
    }
    finally {

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Aca el formulario html que tiene 3 tablas 
el div que dice guias asignadas es el que muestra los registros en un campo de texto llamado txt_mostrar_guias , los registros son de tipo String y se muestran separados por comas uno al lado del otro gracias a una función con javascript.

```
<div class="content container-fluid col-sm-8">
    <div class=" panel-default">
        <div class="title panel-heading">Resultado Vuelos Disponibles</div>
        <div class="panel-body panel panel-primary">
    <form method="POST" action="moverCarga2.do">

       <table class="table table-hover table table-responsive">
            <tr>
                <th class="bg bg-primary">Código</th>
                <th class="bg bg-primary">Iata</th>
                <th class="bg bg-primary">Número</th>
                <th class="bg bg-primary">Fecha</th>
                <th class="bg bg-primary">Estado</th>
                <th class="bg bg-primary">Transito</th>
                <th class="bg bg-primary">Ruta</th>

            </tr>
<%
for(int i=0; i<vuelomovidis.size(); i++)
           {   
               out.println("<tr>");
               out.println("<td><input type='text' size=1 name='txt_id_vuelo_disp' class='form-control' value='"+vuelomovidis.get(i).getIdVuelo()+"'></td>");
               out.println("<td><input type='text' size=10 class='form-control'value='"+vuelomovidis.get(i).getIataVuelo()+"'></td>");
               out.println("<td><input type='text' size=10 class='form-control'value='"+vuelomovidis.get(i).getNumeroVuelo()+"'></td>");
               out.println("<td><input type='text' class='form-control'value='"+vuelomovidis.get(i).getFechaVuelo()+"'></td>");
               out.println("<td><input type='text' class='form-control'value='"+vuelomovidis.get(i).getEstadoVuelo()+"'></td>");
               out.println("<td><input type='text' size=10 class='form-control'value='"+vuelomovidis.get(i).getTipoTransitoVuelo()+"'></td>");
               //out.println("<td><input type='text' class='form-control'value='"+vuelomovi.get(i).getFechaCreacionVuelo()+"'></td>");
               out.println("<td><input type='text' class='form-control'value='"+vuelomovidis.get(i).getRutaVuelo()+"'></td>");
               //out.println("<td><input type='submit' formtarget='frame_vuelo' class='btn btn-success'value='Ver Guías'></td>");


           }
     }
     catch(java.lang.NullPointerException ex)

            {
                out.println("<tr>");
            }


%> 
        </table> 
</div>
        <br>
    <br>
    </div>

<div class="content container-fluid col-lg-10">
    <div class="left panel-default">
        <div class="title panel-heading">Seleccionar guías a mover</div>
        <div class="panel-body panel panel-primary">    

                <table class="table table-hover table table-responsive col-sm-6" id="tabla1">
                   <tbody>
                   <tr id="a1">

                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Awb</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Origen</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Destino</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Piezas</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Kilos</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Volumen</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Id Vuelo</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Tramo</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Mover</th>

                   </tr>



<% 



{
    for(int i=0; i<guia.size(); i++)
           {


                        out.println("<tr id='a2'>");
                        out.println("<td class='cantidad'><input type='text' name='txt_guia'  class='cantidad form-control' value='"+guia.get(i).getNumeroGuia()+"'></td>");

                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getOrigenGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getDestinoGuia()+"</td>");
                        //out.println("<td>"+guia.get(i).getOrigenVueloReserva()+"</td>");

                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getPiezasGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getKilosGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getVolumenGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getIdVueloGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getIdTramoGuia()+"</td>");

                        out.println("<td><input type='checkbox' name='check_guia' class='form-control checkbox' value='"+guia.get(i).getNumeroGuia()+"'></td>");



           }     

}
catch(java.lang.NullPointerException ex)
{
    out.println("<p>'"+ex.getMessage()+"'</p>");
    out.println("</tr>");
}

%>

  </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>      
    </div>


 <div class="content container-fluid col-lg-10">
    <div class="right panel-default">
        <div class="title panel-heading">Guías Asignadas</div>
        <div class="panel-body panel panel-primary">    
                <table class="table table-hover table table-responsive col-sm-6" id="tabla2">
                   <tbody>
                   <tr>

                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Awb</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Origen</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Destino</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Piezas</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Kilos</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Volumen</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Id Vuelo</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Tramo</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Acción</th>
                   </tr>

                </tbody>  
               </table>
            <input type="text" id="txt_mostrar" class="form-control" name="txt_mostrar_guias">

<br><br><br><br>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Asignar" id="boton01">

<input type="resert" class="btn btn-primary" value="Limpiar">

</form> 

</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Aquí la función que me muestra los registros en el campo de texto uno al lado del otro separado por comas.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
```

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
       var tr=$(this).parents("tr").appendTo("#tabla2 tbody");
       var dato = $(this).parents('tr').find('input:text[name="txt_guia"]').val();
       var valor = $('#txt_mostrar').val();
       if (valor == '') {
          $('#txt_mostrar').val(dato);
       } else {
         $('#txt_mostrar').val(valor + ',' + dato);
       }

```
}else{
    // el checkbox esta desmarcado
    // movemos la columna a la tabla1
    var tr=$(this).parents("tr").appendTo("#tabla1 tbody");
    $('#txt_mostrar').val("");
    var valor = '';
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i, check) {
      if($(check).is(":checked")) {
        var dato = $(this).parents('tr').find('input:text[name="txt_guia"]').val();
        var valor = $('#txt_mostrar').val();
        if (valor == '') {
          $('#txt_mostrar').val(dato);
        } else {
          $('#txt_mostrar').val(valor + ',' + dato);
        }
      }
    });
}

});

});

</script>
```

Aqui imagen de cuando se seleccionan las guias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por favor su ayuda para saber si la consulta está mal o algun otro código,
ya que lo que deseo es que se actualicen los registros que seleccionen sea 1 o varios.

Comment: Cuando tienes checkbox y requieres seleccionar varias indica el name como `name="name_de_mi_checkbox[]" value="seguramente_un_id"` esto significa que todos los valores que envíes en ese checkbhox serán solo los valores chequeados, pero el server los recibirá como un array, entonces por ejemplo si tenias los checkbox con valores `1,2,3,4,5` y seleccionas `1,2 y 3`, te llegará al server un array `[1,2,3]` accediendo al name del valor, no recuerdo precisamente como hacer esto con JSP, pero debería ser similar.

Comment: y luego recuerda que la query siempre tiene que estar estructurada así `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE columna IN (val1, val2,val3...valn)` puedes recorrer el array o usar `String.join("", Arrays.asList("val1", "val2"))`

Comment: si entiendo perfectamente , lo que ocurre es que yo estoy capturando directamente del campo de texto txt_mostrar que es el que recibe los datos seleccionados por el checkbox  y es ahí el problema, si en el campo de texto hay un solo registro, este entra en el servlet y se ejecuta la consulta correctamente, pero si el campo de texto tiene mas de un registro, el sistema me dice que actualizó con éxito pero no actualiza realmente.

Comment: Podrias debugear antes? ver efectivamente que está llegando al server. Es ideal antes de comprometer a un insert en la base de datos confirmar que efectivamente te están llegando los datos correctos. A lo que voy es que si te están llegando los datos entonces el problema no está en javascript o formulario, si estos datos no llegan entonces puede ser problema de el formulario.

Comment: si si me actualiza bien los registros de la base de datos, pero solo cuando hay un registro en el campo de texto, pero cuando hay mas de uno es cuando no llegan. debugeare y te cuento.

Comment: Acabo de debugear y no tuve errores de codigo , y si llegan datos al servlet , el problema es que cuando el campo de texto tiene mas de un dato, el serlvet muestra el dato que se envía pero no entra en la consulta sql, solo entra cuando en el campo de texto hay un solo dato.

Comment: Deja ver si entiendo, llega el string con todos los datos? pero al entrar al sql no actualiza?

Comment: si, porque cuando solo hay 1 dato en el campo de texto, el dato entra en la consulta, pero si tiene mas de 1 dato, no entra en la consulta. yo pienso que al ser datos de tipo string, si van como parametros separados por comas, deberian entrar algo ahí '045-1234567','045-4522344', y alomejor están entrando juntos es decir algo así  '045-1234567,045-4522344' como si fuese solo un String y quizas por eso no lo reconoce.

Comment: puedes hacer un `System.out.println(datos_recibidos_texto)` para ver la estructura por favor y descartar ello, estoy casi seguro que la estructura del string presenta problemas, pero sin verla nada se puede hacer

Comment: en el System  se muestra así Información:   Conexion exitosa :)
Información:   las guias estan llegando como :145-89542389,145-78236734,549-123465432

Comment: ok, entonces tu sql debería ser así `UPDATE la_tabla set fila1= valor_1 WHERE cierto_campo IN ('145-89542389','145-78236734','549-123465432')`

Comment: Usa esto que te mencioné antes `String.join(",", Arrays.asList("val1", "val2"))` e intenta llegar a la estructura `cada uno de los valores envueltos en comilla simple y separados por coma`

Comment: Una pregunta, el String.join lo utilizo en la consulta directamente o en el servlet ?

Comment: Deja ver eso y te lo dejo como respuesta, al menos ya se identifica el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Después de una larga conversa en los comentarios, se identificó que el problema estaba en como llegan los String al servlet o más bien, como estos se están enviando a al query

```
SQLUpdate="UPDATE tvas t\n" +
              "INNER JOIN rvas r\n" +
              "ON(t.rvas_cod_seq_rvas = r.cod_seq_rvas)\n" +
              "INNER JOIN awb a\n" +
              "on(r.awb_cod_seq_awb=a.cod_seq_awb)\n" +
              "SET t.vlos_seq_vlos ='"+v.getIdVuelo()+"'\n" +
              "WHERE a.awb in('"+f.getNumeroFolioCompleto()+"');";
```

El problema radica en que los checkbox que se llenan envían la información de la forma `'numero1, numero2, numero3'` por lo tanto la forma del in quedaría de la siguiente forma:

`IN ('NUM1, NUM2,NUM3')`, lo cual no funcionaría, IN debe tener los valores entre comilla simple separado por coma, dependiendo del RDBM que se ocupe.

Entonces el problema se transfroma en uno de [string-manipulation](/questions/tagged/string-manipulation)

Una forma es que puedes tomar el mismo string y transformarlo a la estructura que necesitas.

**Snippet o función**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Tu String, por supuesto lo obtienes como un parámetro en
    // tu función una vez que establezcas donde dejar, nombre, etc
    String str =  "045-1234567,045-4522344";

    // Similar a PHP explode function, explotar el string en la coma
    // para generar un array de string
    String [] arrOfStr = str.split(",", 5);

    // El string que se generará
    String strret= "";

    // For-each loop
    for (String a : arrOfStr){
                // vamos agregando cada string envuelto en comillas
                // y dejar una coma al final
                strret = strret+ "'"+a+"',";
    }

    // remover la coma al final, o sumale + "0"
    if (strret.charAt(strret.length() - 1) == ',') {
        strret = strret.substring(0, strret.length() - 1);
    }

    System.out.println(strret);
    //o return strret;
}
```

**Salida**

```
  '045-1234567','045-4522344'
```

Ahora este string se lo pasas a la query

```
   String query = "UPDATE tablita "
                + "SET valor = 'algo' "
                + "WHERE alguna_columna IN ("+resultado_de_la_función+")";
```

Comment: Ya resolví el problema solo había que agregar "" en el codigo de javascript valor + "','" + dato y así el dato pasa correctamente al servlet y ejecuta la consulta correctamente.  De todas maneras guardare tu ejemplo Gracias.